# When do a triangle and its Morely triangle have the same centroid

Tags: plane-geometry

When do a triangle and its Morley triangle have the same centroid?
For definition of the Morley Triangle see

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morley's_trisector_theorem#Morley.27s_triangles

Comment: When and only when the original triangle is equilateral (as with the coincidence of most triangle centres).  You could prove this with trilinear coordinates if you wish

Answer (score 1):

See whether this link helps you: http://jwilson.coe.uga.edu/emt668/EMAT6680.F99/Erbas/emat6690/essay2/essay2.html

Comment: +1 for the interesting  link, in particular for the information on second Morley center.  However it does not contain my answer.